# Difference between average and expected value

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I am new in statistics, I don't understand what's the difference between expected value and average, only two different ways to calculate samething. For example if i am given a table(relative frequency) like this. $(1/10, 1/20, 1/2)$now if i say $f(0) = 1/10 , f(1) = 1/20 , f(2) = 1/2$ which means that one out of ten men have good osense of locality ,second one has middle and third one has bad sense of locality. If i compute expected value then it will be equal to $m*f(m)$ , so i have $E(X) = (0*(1/10)+1(1/20)+2(1/2))$ and this results in $1.05$. Is it right? can someone tell me what's the difference between average and Expected value?

Comment: What kind of "average" do you refer to? Please note that there are many different kinds of averages, and that they can apply to arbitrary batches of numbers, but that expected value has a single well-established definition and applies only to random variables.  Note, too, that your example is neither an average nor an expected value, because your relative frequencies do not sum to unity.

Comment: Sample average.

Comment: I don't fully understand your example of good/bad sense of locality, but it seems to me that the computation of the expected value is incorrect. The expected value of a discrete random variable is the probability-weighted average of all the possible values, implying that the probabilities must sum up to 1. This is not the case in your example, 1/10 + 1/20 + 1/2 = 0.65

Comment: There are *many* forms of "sample average," including (but not limited to) the median, mode, arithmetic mean, geometric mean, harmonic mean, and midrange.

Comment: @MatteoLisi i understand that they must sum up to 1, but this vector is only for man and i am only interested to compute the expected value for men, the other vector for women is like : (1/5, 1/10, 1/20) and this sums up to .35+.65 = 1. What i am trying to do is that i associated a 0 with a man having bad sense of locality ,1 for middle and 2 for a man having good sense of locality. So is it wrong to compute like this?

Comment: Yes it is wrong. If you are interested in the expected value for men you have to use the relative frequencies computed within the men's group. Since your frequencies do not sum to 1 your estimate is smaller that the correct value which is ~ 1.61. Note that if what you have is a sample, what you are computing is the arithmetic average of this locality-score, not the expected value. The sample average is an approximation of the expected-value and can be understood as the average of the whole population (or as the long-run average when the number of repetitions of approach infinity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Disclaimer:** I'm new too, but here is my answer in case it helps you (or helps me by being corrected by the experts).*

So, when you look at any population, such as the population of rubber ducks sold in Walmart in USA, you will find that the population of such rubber ducks has some properties, such as the arithmetic mean of the weight of the rubber ducks, or the arithmetic mean of their volume, etc --- these *properties* are called *statistics*.  So the arithmetic mean of the weights of the rubber ducks in Walmart is a *statistic*.  Likewise, the arithmetic mean volume of the rubber ducks is yet another statistic.

The term *average* refers to a special kind of a *statistic*.  Now, which *statistic*?  It seems that the term *average* is sort of flexible and allows it to be defined in different ways.  Which I think why whuber asked you *"what kind of average ... ?"*.

It seems to me that the actual definition of *average*, in your question, is not really important to answer your question.  So let's leave how *average* is defined aside, and look at it as *some statistic about some population*.

Now, what is the expected value?  Well, the _expected value, is, as the name says, our expectation/guess of what a statistic's value should be.  Let me give you an example.

In the case when our *statistic* is defined to be *"the arithmetic mean of the weight of rubber ducks in Walmart"*, our *expected value of the statistic* becomes our guess of the value of that statistic --- But you may ask, what is the point?  Why should we ask about our guess of that statistic?

Suppose that we don't know the actual value of the statistic (i.e. arithmetic mean of weight of rubber ducks in Walmart), but all we know weight of only $100$ rubber ducks that were uniformly and randomly sampled across Walmart stores in USA.  In this case, the expected value (i.e. our guess) of the *statistic* is:

$$\begin{split}
E[\text{statistic}] 
&= \frac{1}{100} 1\text{kg} + \frac{1}{100} 1.01\text{kg} + \frac{1}{100} 0.98\text{kg} + \ldots \\
&= \frac{1}{100} (1\text{kg} + 1.01\text{kg} + 0.98\text{kg} + \ldots) \\
\end{split}$$

Here, we normalized each observation (weight of a single rubber duck in Walmart) by $1/100$ since we sampled them randomly and uniformly.

But what if we sampled them in a biased way?  Such that $50$ of the rubber ducks came from a small Walmart store that has only $10\%$ of total Walmart's rubber ducks in USA, while the remaining $50$ sampled rubber ducks came from one of Walmart's largest stores that contain, say, $90\%$ of total Walmart's rubber ducks in USA (only two Walmart stores sell rubber ducks in this example).

In that case our expected value of the statistic becomes:

$$\begin{split}
E[\text{statistic from store 1}] 
&= \frac{1}{50} (1\text{kg} + 1.01\text{kg} + 0.98\text{kg} + \ldots) = 1\\
\end{split}$$

$$\begin{split}
E[\text{statistic from store 2}] 
&= \frac{1}{50} (0.78\text{kg} + 0.9\text{kg} + 0.83\text{kg} + \ldots) = 0.87\\
\end{split}$$

Then the statistic becomes:

$$\begin{split}
E[\text{statistic}] 
&= 0.1 \times E[\text{statistic from store 1}] & + 0.9 \times E[\text{statistic from store 2}] \\
&= 0.1 \times 1 & + 0.9 \times 0.87 \\
\end{split}$$

As you see, our guess of the statistic, aka the expected value of the statistic, changes based on the information that we have.  E.g. initially our guess of the statistic was simply the arithmetic mean of the $100$ samples, and it was a good guess since the the samples were uniformly and randomly taken.  But then, as got other information saying that our samples are biased, we calculated our guess (i.e. expected value) differently.

So back to your question.  What is the difference between the expected value, and the average?  The difference is that:

- The *expected value* is a guess for a statistic's value.
- The *average* could be a guess, i.e. an expected value, because sometimes *average* is used to calculate such guess.  But *average* could be the statistic itself that we try to measure (e.g. if we define average to be the arithmetic mean of rubber ducks weight in all Walmart stores in USA).

In other words, your question sounds like:  what's the difference between an orange, and fruit.  Maybe not exactly, but I hope it gives you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The expected values is a **population concept**, the average is a **statistic** that you can compute in sample. The average is used because it is often a good approximation for the expected value.

In your example, you assume that the relative frequencies in sample are the same as the probability mass function of your random variable in population, that is why average and expected value coincide.